# Orientation bug for react-native

Tags: react-native, mobile

I'm using React-Native for my work and I'm developing an app. However, it runs into a weird bug that I failed to figure it out how to fix.

It has to do with styling for different orientations.

For example, when I run my app in portrait mode, the different orientation styles work fine but not in landscape mode, each orientation seems to get messed up (the styles get bigger).

Have you ever encountered this problem?

Comment: I would suggest supporting your question with sample code that you used to possibly we can easily see what you are doing wrong in your CSS file.

Comment: @NamwanzaRonald there is no css in react-native.
@gavinNguyen I guess you haven't understand ```flexbox``` yet.
In case a View has the style property ```flex:1``` it will expand and use all available space.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.